# How to add logo in Thematic

Tags: themes

I've done my sharing of hacking themes before, especially to replace the site title with a logo, but for newest thematic theme, I can't figure out where to edit the code to add my logo. I've checked header.php and the style.css but can't figure it out.

http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/thematic

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a css background image for your logo.

Go to line 65 of default.css and change

```
#blog-title {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:34px;
    font-weight:bold;
    line-height:40px;
}
```

To This:

```
#blog-title {
background: url(images/path_to_your_logo.png) no-repeat;
display:block;
width: 00px; /* enter logo width */
height: 00px; /* enter logo height */
text-indent: -999em; /* replaces blog title with your logo */
}
```

Comment: thanks! worked like a charm! For those who will read this later, the path is: themes/thematic/library/styles/default.css

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress development best practice is to implement a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to override defaults. If you edit the Thematic files directly, you will lose changes when Thematic is updated.

Please refer to [Create child theme of Thematic WordPress Theme Framework](http://noseyparka.me.uk/2012/07/28/create-child-theme-of-thematic-wordpress-theme-framework/) to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/2009/05/28/add-a-header-image-to-thematic-the-easy-way/comment-page-2/#comments

I'm not sure if this is too over the top, but seems a cool way to do it.  Hopefully this is still up to date (it appears so judging by the comment thread)

It adds an option panel for uploading header images.....

Comment: Thanks Rev. Voodoo! The only thing was that this was the main Thematic theme not a child theme so the tutorial would have required extra steps.

Comment: Right.... child themes are a good habit to get into.  I'm not sure, but doesn't the thematic get updated at all?  If so, and you aren't using a child theme, you would lose your edits upon an upgrade to thematic